# Defining a function with two different template paramenter

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code

```
template< typename T>
struct S{
     T x,y;
     S(T a, T b) : x(a) , y(b) {}
};

using Di = S<int>;
using Dd = S<double>;

auto foo(Dd d){
          ..........
}
```

Now my doubt is: suppose I am calling `foo()` with parameter of type `Di` then it's an error of incorrect reference type.

I know that one solution is to use `auto` here as it works . But in general I want to know is there any other method so that my function works for both parameter types.

Comment: That's easy. Make your function, itself, a template function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the function a template:

```
template<typename T>
auto foo(S<T> d){
  // ...
}
```

Now you can call `foo` with any instantiation of `S`.

---

If you want to constrain the function template to only accept instantiations of `S` with either `int` or `double`, you can do that check inside the function:

```
template<typename T>
auto foo(S<T> d){
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, int> || std::is_same_v<T, double>);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: You could also implement ```int foo(S<int> d)``` and ```double foo(S<double> d)``` directly.

Comment: @Homer6 True, but OP has asked for *a* function, so writing 2 functions wouldn't really answer the question.

Comment: You might be right. But, he was also asking generally for any other methods.

Comment: @Homer6 That's true. You could make an answer that enumerates some options. I'd like to keep my answer short and to the point :)

Comment: Also @Homer6 to make two seperate function is also an option but i was knowing that before hand so i was looking for more specific one.. It's waste of space to write two different function for same task... anways thanks for the reply... :)

Comment: @cigien But what you've done is _also_ writing two functions. The fact is that you wrote just one function _template_. But a function template is not a function; it is a template for functions.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Yes. Did I mispeak in the answer, or are you referring to my comment responding to Homer6?

Comment: @cigien Yes your comment. _"True, but OP has asked for a function, so writing 2 functions wouldn't really answer the question."_.

Answer (score 1):

`S<int>` and `S<double>` (a.k.a. `Di` and `Dd`) are two different types.

Period.

It doesn't matter that they are template instantiations.

So, do what you'd normally do when you need a function to take an argument of one of two or more types:

- make it take a variant, or
- make it a template, or
- write an overload